# ROS melodic with python3 got openCV error

Tags: opencv, ros

as mentioned on title I'm trying to use ros melodic with python3. First error pop up because of cv_bridge and it has been fixed. Now I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] [1673464074.204372, 2767.036000]: bad callback: <function im_callback at 0x7f889d1aed90>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-civioau0/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:586:
error: (-2:Unspecified error) Const input blob for weights not found in function 'getConstBlob'
```

I checked and could not find anything about this error.

Here is my code that I'm trying to rosrun:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import rospy
import sensor_msgs.msg as sensor
import cv_bridge

rostopic = "/iris/camera/rgb/image_raw"
rosmsg = sensor.Image
configPath = "/home/irene/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/model/ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt" #file.pbtxt
modelPath = "/home/irene/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/model/frozen_inference_graph.pb" #file.pb
classesPath = "/home/irene/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/model/coco.names" #file.names
bridge = cv_bridge.CvBridge()

def im_callback(rosmsg):
    global configPath, modelPath, classesPath, bridge
    img = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(rosmsg, "bgr8")

    net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(modelPath, configPath)
    net.setInputSize(320,320)
    net.setInputScale(1/127.5)
    net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
    net.setInputSwapRB(True)

    with open(classesPath, "r") as file:
        classesList = file.read().splitlines()

    classesLabelIDs, confidences, body_rects = net.detect(img, confThreshold = 0.6)

    body_rects = list(body_rects)
    confidences = list(np.array(confidences).reshape(1,-1)[0])
    confidences = list(map(float, confidences))

    bboxsIDx = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(body_rects, confidences, score_threshold=0.5, nms_threshold = 0.2) 

    if len(bboxsIDx) != 0:
        for _, bID in enumerate(bboxsIDx):
            classLabelID = np.squeeze(classesLabelIDs[np.squeeze(bID)])
            classLabel = classesList[classLabelID]

            if classLabel == "person":
                body_rect = body_rects[np.squeeze(bID)]
                classConfidence = confidences[np.squeeze(bID)]

                display_text = "{} - {:.1}".format(classLabel, classConfidence)

                x,y,w,h = body_rect
                        
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 1)
                cv2.line(img, (x,y), (x+ int(w*.3), y), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.line(img, (x,y), (x, y + int(h*.3)), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.line(img, (x+w,y), (x + w - int(w*.3), y), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.line(img, (x+w,y), (x+w, y + int(h*.3)), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.line(img, (x+w,y+h), (x + w - int(w*.3), y + h), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.line(img, (x+w,y+h), (x+w, y + h - int(h*.3)), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.line(img, (x,y+h), (x + int(w*.3), y+h), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.line(img, (x,y+h), (x, y + h -int(h*.3)), (0,0,255), 3)
                cv2.putText(img, display_text, (x, y-8), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, .4, (255,255,255), 1)

        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

def main():
    global rosmsg, rostopic
    
    rospy.init_node("webcam_node", anonymous=True)
    

    rospy.Subscriber(rostopic, rosmsg, im_callback)
    rospy.spin()
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I was trying to use ROS melodic with python3 and I got this error

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably gathered, the error is because of you're trying to use Python3. Melodic targets Python2.7 exclusively and it's highly not recommended to try and make it run with Python3 for the reasons you're seeing. If you really want to use Python3 packages and dependencies in your project, you should instead be running the Noetic distro of ROS.